How to activate/access keyboard backlight controls?
Currently using a 2018 Dell Latitude 7490 running GNOME 46 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I have a keyboard backlight currently but the lights only turn on when keyboard is in use.
Any way to access controls?

See at: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-lc/000177038/c%C3%B3mo-configurar-el-teclado-la-retroiluminaci%C3%B3n-el-tiempo-de-espera-el-intervalo-en-ubuntu-y-linux
